# How to share `abbrev_defs` across multiple systems

Tags: abbrev, configuration-files

I keep my `abbrev_defs` file in a git repository so I can share my abbreviations across systems. Unfortunately, the count feature of `abbrev-mode` leads to little changes in the `:count` property of defined abbreviations in this file that makes merging a big hassle.

Is there a good way to fix this?

I would be happy to just disable counting how often I use an abbreviation or saving this but there doesn't seem to be any built-in way to do this in the source of `abbrev.el`. I could advise `write-abbrev-file` to remove all counts from all abbrev tables first but that seems pretty clunky.

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy ignoring the `:count` properties, then you could try this:

Say the value of `abbrev-file-name` is `abbrev.el`.  Create a copy of that file, say `my-abbrev.el`.  Add `abbrev.el` to `.gitignore`, add `my-abbrev.el` to your repository.  Add the following to your init file:

```
(quietly-read-abbrev-file "~/.emacs.d/my-abbrev.el")
```

When you want to add or modify an abbrev, do so directly in `my-abbrev.el` rather than via the standard commands (`add-global-abbrev`, etc.)